# How to represent a bytes array with DB Rider in YAML configuration

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit, dbrider

I have a series of test cases using `Spring Jdbc`, `Database Rider`, and `H2` — with `Java 17.x`. Everything works fine, but I can't find a way to represent a byte array in the YAML configuration file :/

This is what I have:

```java
@Getter
@Builder
public final class Category {
  ...

  private byte[] picture;
}
```

```java
public class CategoryJdbc implements ICategoryJdbc {
  private static final RowMapper<Category> ROW_MAPPER = (rs, rowNum) -> Category.builder()
      ...
      .picture(rs.getBytes("picture"))
      .build();

  private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public Optional<Category> findById(final Long primaryKey) {
    final var result = template.queryForObject(queries.getProperty("find-category-by-identifier"),
        new MapSqlParameterSource("id", primaryKey), ROW_MAPPER);
    return Optional.ofNullable(result);
  }
}
```

```java
@DBRider
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class CategoryJdbcTest {
  @Autowired
  private ICategoryJdbc jdbc;

  @Test
  @DataSet("categories.yml")
  void findById_WhenEntityExists() {
    Assertions.assertThat(jdbc.findById(1L)).hasValueSatisfying(it -> {
      Assertions.assertThat(it.getId()).isEqualTo(1);
      Assertions.assertThat(it.getName()).isEqualTo("Beverages");
      Assertions.assertThat(it.getDescription()).isEqualTo("Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales");
      Assertions.assertThat(it.getPicture())
          .isEqualTo(new byte[] { 0x4c, 0x6f, 72, 65, 0x6d, 20, 69, 70, 73, 75, 0x6d });
    });
  }
}
```

```yaml
categories:
  - id: 1
    name: "Beverages"
    description: "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales"
    picture: \x4c6f72656d20697073756d # Lorem ipsum
```

> For testing, I converted `Lorem ipsum` to a bytes array: `4c 6f 72 65 6d 20 69 70 73 75 6d`.

Does anyone knows how to represent the same in the YAML file, in such way that `rs.getBytes("picture")` interprets it correctly?

I've tested this with the built-in `H2` [binary data types](https://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#binary_type) as well — because `bytea` is built-in a `PostgreSQL` data type, but looks like it works as well in `H2`, even though I don't see it listed in `H2`'s website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching all over the places I found [this](https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider/issues/216) issue. Looks like `Database Rider` needs the binary data "converted" with (the popular) `Base 64` binary-to-text algorithm. I think that makes sense, but I was under the assumption that all configuration files would store the data, in exactly the same format as the database — but for binary data, they have a small "indirection" layer.

Anyway, for my example, I took the `Lorem ipsum` string as my data source. I then converted this string to a bytes array: `new byte[] { 76, 111, 114, 101, 109, 32, 105, 112, 115, 117, 109 }`, and finally encoded the resultant bytes array into `Base64`: `TG9yZW0gaXBzdW0=` ...and that's how it should be stored in the configuration files for `Database Rider`.

> I use this snippet `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("Lorem ipsum".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))` to do all the *conversion ceremony*.